# What cause row chart error when re-rendering from no data to some data?

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I have a problem with re-drawing DC js row chart if its changing from no data to some data in the row chart. I will get the error of `d3.js:663 Error: <text> attribute y: Expected length, "Infinity".`

Here's the illustration of the error with screenshot and description. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Caq5Z.jpg

Basically the error happens when it re-renders row chart from no data to some data.

Is there any config or solution with DC js to solve this problem?

This is the piece of code for me to render row chart

````
        const group = this.chart.group(dim).reduceCount();
        const chart = this.cs.setChart(this.chart.dimension, dc.rowChart(`#${this.chart.dimension}`)
            .width(SMALL_WIDTH)
            .height(SMALL_HEIGHT)
            .dimension(dim)
            .cap(this.chart.cap)
            .othersGrouper(false)
            .elasticX(true)
            .group(group)
            .autoScroll(true));

        chart.dc.margins().left = 5;
        chart.dc.margins().right = 0;
        chart.dc.xAxis().ticks(2);

        chart.dc.on('preRedraw', (c) => {
            this.cfs.updates.next(c);
        });```
````

Comment: I take it the errors in the console don't prevent the chart from working? We have never been great about eliminating these sorts of DOM value errors when there is no breakage in the chart itself. For one thing, there doesn't seem to be any way to detect such errors programmatically. IIRC they don't even hit the `console` object but go direct to the browser debug console.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't prevent the chart from working properly, and it still shows the correct data. Its just annoying to see the error on browser console and I want to get rid of it. So you don't think there's a solution to this?

Comment: I'm sure there is a workaround... an actual solution would probably need to go into the library.

Comment: Alright thank heaps, I'll probably just not render the chart when they have no data as a workaround solution.

Comment: Yep, that's probably the best workaround!

Comment: You could also render instead of redraw whenever switching data sets. The animated transitions aren't all that useful when switching data sets.